# Integrating Spotify in react native

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to integrate the Favorite Song From Spotify feature to be included in the app's user profile.

So the user can pick and choose a song from Spotify.

I'm not able to find good documentation that supports such a thing.

Any help would be appreciated.